# Launch and control javafx GUI from another class

Tags: java, class, controller, javafx, extends

I have one class/file, ui/.class, which extends Application and deals with the ui of my program. I also have another class file, core/.class, which I want to deal with all the logic of the program. So, in core.class I have:

```
class core{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ui GUI = new ui();
      GUI.launch();
   }
}
```

This compiles fine, but gives a runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class core is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
```

Should my core class extend Application? If so, why?

EDIT: Here's the ui class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.stage.*;

import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;


public class ui extends Application{
    public void start(Stage mainStage){
        mainStage.setTitle("UI Test");      
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();     
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(mainPane);
        mainStage.setScene(mainScene);
        mainStage.show();
    }
}
```